# PHP check if array values are set

Tags: php, arrays, function

I've got the following function:

```
public function insertMember($username, $password, $fname, $lname)
    {
        $param              = array();
        $param['username']  = $username;
        $param['password']  = $password;
        $param['fname']     = $fname;
        $param['lname']     = $lname;
        return (count(array_filter($param, 'strlen')) == 0) ? FALSE : $this->insertIntoDB($param);
    }
```

Is using `(count(array_filter($param, 'strlen')) == 0)` the right/best way to go about checking if all the variables `$username, $password, $fname, $lname` have been passed to the function?

Thanks,
Pav

Comment: Your param list doesn't have any default values, so in order to call this function you *must* supply 4 parameters no matter what. Data validation on the other hand is still important.

Comment: @Chris Well, all it'll do is issue a warning, you're still not forced to pass all 4 parameters.

Comment: @deceze Bah, it's only a warning? Silly PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really check whether the variables have been passed to the function or not, you can only check their value. If the value is *falsey*, you may reject it. That doesn't necessarily mean that the variable wasn't passed, just that the value was *falsey*.

```
if (!$username || !$password || !$fname || !$lname)
```

To restrict it a bit more and accept, for example, empty strings and 0 as valid values, do something like:

```
public function insertMember($username = null, $password = null, $fname = null, $lname = null) {
    if ($username === null || $password === null || $fname === null || $lname === null)
```

The best way may be to accept an array, which you can explicitly test for the existence of keys, regardless of their values:

```
public function insertMember($values) {
    if (array_diff_key(array_flip(array('username', 'password', 'fname', 'lname')), $values)) {
        // not all keys were set!
    }
```

Regardless, this:

```
$param             = array();
$param['username'] = $username;
$param['password'] = $password;
$param['fname']    = $fname;
$param['lname']    = $lname;
```

can be shortened to:

```
$params = compact('username', 'password', 'fname', 'lname');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(count(array_filter($array)) == 0)
//   all values are empty
```

Comment: You should expand your answer to explain how this satisfies the question, and provide a more relevant example of how it could be used in the context of the question.

Comment: here is an example for this answer :

Answer (score 1):

Maybe right but not best.
If you need to check all variables:

```
if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($fname) || empty($lname)) return false;
```

Comment: I've got number of functions that are similar and need to check if the values have been passed/set. So i don't really want to check each variable by it self, would much rather assign them to an array and do a check like in my post. Was just wondering if it the best way to go about it? Or there is an alternative way(without checking each variable)?

Comment: It's more looks like worst way. Do you want or not - it's not a question. If you have to check - you will check. Each variable.

Comment: This is exactly what array_filter does, but you have chosen the dirty way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the `'strlen'` parameter, the default behavior of `array_filter` will work fine in this case. This way the code is just a tad shorter.

However, as a matter of style you may want to consider the explicit

```
if (empty($username) || empty($password) || ...)
```

because it more readily communicates to the reader what the requirements of the function are as regards its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put your check even early? Make it something like that:

```
public function insertMember($username, $password, $fname, $lname) {
    if (!$username || !$password || !$fname || !lname) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $param = array();
        $param['username'] = $username;
        $param['password'] = $password;
        $param['fname'] = $fname;
        $param['lname'] = $lname;
        return $this->insertIntoDB($param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't check the validity of the data but:

```
// Do something if 4 (all) arguments were passed in
if(func_num_args() == 4) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not using `array_filter` since it feels kind of dirty to pass a function in by its name. Although if you're using stdlib functions it may be okay.

I would use a loop

```
foreach ($param as $v) {
    if (empty($v)) return false;
}
```